# How do I make a while loop that breaks when the input is <enter>?

Tags: python

I am making a Python program for a school project and I want to say: 'If input is <enter> break'. I tried to write:

```
a = input('>')

if a == '\n':
    break
```

and it didn't work. How do I fix this?

Comment: `input()` does not include the newline character that ended the user's typing.  To detect a blank line, you'd use `if a == '':` (or simply `if not a:`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: "If input is break" What does that *mean*? Anyway, here's a quick way that you can figure out how to write this code: type the interesting input at the prompt, and then *see what the value of `a` is*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Formatting issue... See edit

Answer (score 0):

When a user presses the enter key, the input taken is a blank string. so you want your code to say:

```
if a == "":
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your desired code. It breaks the loop when you only press the enter button as input:

```
while True:
    a= input()
    if a =='':
        break
    else: continue
```

Comment: Why use `else continue` if without `continue`, it will continue?

Comment: yes, you're right. It'll work without the else continue command but I added that for best practices.